# Django, keeps redirecting to the wrong page

Tags: django, url

So I'm trying to make a payment page which I did but I'm having an issue when you click on the button "Submit Payment" It's supposed to send you back to the home page while also displaying a message. I have tried multiple solutions but I can't figure out where the part is that tells it to redirect to the page called /payment

Here's my code;

```
class PaymentView(View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        order = Order.objects.get(user=self.request.user, ordered=False)
        context = {
            'order': order
        }
        return render(self.request, "payment.html", context)

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        order = Order.objects.get(user=self.request.user, ordered=False)
        token = self.request.POST.get('stripeToken')
        amount = int(order.get_total() * 100)

        try:
            charge = stripe.Charge.create(
                amount=amount,  # cents
                currency="eur",
                source=token
            )

            # create the payment
            payment = Payment()
            payment.stripe_charge_id = charge['id']
            payment.user = self.request.user
            payment.amount = order.get_total()
            payment.save()

            # assign the payment to the order

            order.ordered = True
            order.payment = payment
            order.save()

            messages.success(self.request, "Your order was successful!")
            return redirect("/")

        except stripe.error.CardError as e:
            body = e.json_body
            err = body.get('error', {})
            messages.error(self.request, f"{err.get('message')}")
            return redirect("/")

        except stripe.error.RateLimitError as e:
            # Too many requests made to the API too quickly
            messages.error(self.request, "Rate limit error")
            return redirect("/")

        except stripe.error.InvalidRequestError as e:
            # Invalid parameters were supplied to Stripe's API
            messages.error(self.request, "Invalid parameters")
            return redirect("/")

        except stripe.error.AuthenticationError as e:
            # Authentication with Stripe's API failed
            # (maybe you changed API keys recently)
            messages.error(self.request, "Not authenticated")
            return redirect("/")

        except stripe.error.APIConnectionError as e:
            # Network communication with Stripe failed
            messages.error(self.request, "Network error")
            return redirect("/")

        except stripe.error.StripeError as e:
            # Display a very generic error to the user, and maybe send
            # yourself an email
            messages.error(
                self.request, "Something went wrong. You were not charged. Please try again.")
            return redirect("/")

        except Exception as e:
            # send an email to ourselves
            messages.error(
                self.request, "A serious error occurred. We have been notifed.")
            return redirect("/")
```

And this is my payment.html file;

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block extra_head%}
<style>

#stripeBtnLabel {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-variant: normal;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

#stripeBtn {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: #32325d;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0 14px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(50, 50, 93, .11), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .08);
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 0.025em;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 150ms ease;
  transition: all 150ms ease;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 12px;
  margin-top: 28px;
}

button:hover {
  transform: translateY(-1px);
  box-shadow: 0 7px 14px rgba(50, 50, 93, .10), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .08);
  background-color: #43458b;
}

#stripe-form {
  padding: 30px;
  height: 120px;
}

label {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

#card-errors {
  height: 20px;
  padding: 4px 0;
  color: #fa755a;
}

.stripe-form-row {
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
}

/**
 * The CSS shown here will not be introduced in the Quickstart guide, but shows
 * how you can use CSS to style your Element's container.
 */
.StripeElement {
  box-sizing: border-box;

  height: 40px;

  padding: 10px 12px;

  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: white;

  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #e6ebf1;
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow 150ms ease;
  transition: box-shadow 150ms ease;
}

.StripeElement--focus {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #cfd7df;
}

.StripeElement--invalid {
  border-color: #fa755a;
}

.StripeElement--webkit-autofill {
  background-color: #fefde5 !important;
}
</style>
{% endblock extra_head %}

{% block content %}

  <main class="mt-5 pt-4">
    <div class="container wow fadeIn">

      <!-- Veebilehe pealkiri -->
      <h2 class="my-5 h2 text-center">Maksmine</h2>

      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-12 mb-4">

          <div class="card">

            <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>

            <form action="." method="post" id="stripe-form">
              {% csrf_token %}
              <div class="stripe-form-row">
                <label for="card-element" id="stripeBtnLabel">
                  Credit or debit card
                </label>
                <div id="card-element" class="StripeElement StripeElement--empty"><div class="__PrivateStripeElement" style="margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; border: none !important; display: block !important; background: transparent !important; position: relative !important; opacity: 1 !important;"><iframe frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" name="__privateStripeFrame5" allowpaymentrequest="true" src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/elements-inner-card-76bab651464ea5f1b989a9bad010b28b.html#style[base][color]=%2332325d&amp;style[base][fontFamily]=%22Helvetica+Neue%22%2C+Helvetica%2C+sans-serif&amp;style[base][fontSmoothing]=antialiased&amp;style[base][fontSize]=16px&amp;style[base][::placeholder][color]=%23aab7c4&amp;style[invalid][color]=%23fa755a&amp;style[invalid][iconColor]=%23fa755a&amp;componentName=card&amp;wait=false&amp;rtl=false&amp;keyMode=test&amp;apiKey=pk_test_TYooMQauvdEDq54NiTphI7jx&amp;origin=https%3A%2F%2Fstripe.com&amp;referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fstripe.com%2Fdocs%2Fstripe-js&amp;controllerId=__privateStripeController1" title="Secure payment input frame" style="border: none !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; width: 1px !important; min-width: 100% !important; overflow: hidden !important; display: block !important; user-select: none !important; height: 19.2px;"></iframe><input class="__PrivateStripeElement-input" aria-hidden="true" aria-label=" " autocomplete="false" maxlength="1" style="border: none !important; display: block !important; position: absolute !important; height: 1px !important; top: 0px !important; left: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; margin: 0px !important; width: 100% !important; opacity: 0 !important; background: transparent !important; pointer-events: none !important; font-size: 16px !important;"></div></div>

                <!-- Used to display form errors. -->
                <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
              </div>
            {% comment %} <a class="nav-link waves-effect" href="/"> {% endcomment %}
              <button id="stripeBtn">Submit Payment</button></a>
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>


        <!--Grid column-->
        <div class="col-md-12 mb-4">

          <!-- Heading -->
          <h4 class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-3">
            <span class="text-muted">Teie ostukorv</span>
            <span class="badge badge-danger badge-pill">{{ order.items.count }}</span>
          </h4>

          <ul class="list-group mb-3 z-depth-1">
            {% for order_item in order.items.all %}
            <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between lh-condensed">
              <div>
                <h6 class="my-0">{{ order_item.quantity}} x {{ order_item.item.title }}</h6>
                <small class="text-muted">{{ order_item.item.description }}</small>
              </div>
              <span class="text-muted">{{ order_item.get_final_price }}€</span>
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
            <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between bg-light">
              <div class="text-success">
                <h6 class="my-0">Promo code</h6>
                <small>EXAMPLECODE</small>
              </div>
              <span class="text-success">-$5</span>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between">
              <span>Kokku:</span>
              <strong>{{ order.get_total }}€</strong>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <!-- Cart -->


        </div>
        <!--Grid column-->
      </div>

    </div>
  </main>


<script type="text/javascript" nonce="">  // Create a Stripe client.
  var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_TYooMQauvdEDq54NiTphI7jx');

  // Create an instance of Elements.
  var elements = stripe.elements();

  // Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
  // (Note that this demo uses a wider set of styles than the guide below.)
  var style = {
    base: {
      color: '#32325d',
      fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
      fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
      fontSize: '16px',
      '::placeholder': {
        color: '#aab7c4'
      }
    },
    invalid: {
      color: '#fa755a',
      iconColor: '#fa755a'
    }
  };

  // Create an instance of the card Element.
  var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});

  // Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
  card.mount('#card-element');

  // Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.
  card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
    if (event.error) {
      displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
    } else {
      displayError.textContent = '';
    }
  });

  // Handle form submission.
  var form = document.getElementById('stripe-form');
  form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
      if (result.error) {
        // Inform the user if there was an error.
        var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
        errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
      } else {
        // Send the token to your server.
        stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
      }
    });
  });

  // Submit the form with the token ID.
  function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
    // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    var form = document.getElementById('stripe-form');
    var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
    form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

    // Submit the form
    form.submit();
  }

</script>

{% endblock content %}
```

Thanks in advance, 
Nimetu

Comment: please share your template codes

Comment: Check above @ruddra

Comment: try using `actions='/the url you want to post'` instead of `actions='.'`

Comment: the action attribute of form specifies where to send the form-data when a form is submitted. set `action="/your/url/"` and `method="post"`

Comment: Thanks it worked.